# allow users to login to the domain on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I have created a new user on windows server 2008, but this user is unable to login to the domain. so which permision i should grant to this user to be able to login to his machine inside the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

All users should, when created, should automatically be added to the group `Domain Users`.  If they are in that group and not able to log in, then something else is wrong.  Perhaps their account is disabled, not active, locked out, etc...  There could be many reasons.  What error is this person receiving?

Comment: i added him to the DomainUsers and i reset his password, but still he can not login to his machine ?

Comment: what is the error?  is the machine a part of the domain?